# MK Mapview get directions using route cloud made apis

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, mkmapview

I am developing code for the map view in iphone where I was able to show route on the map. Here by this api,

http://routes.cloudmade.com/8ee2a50541944fb9bcedded5165f09d9/api/0.3/47.25976,9.58423,47.26117,9.59882/car/shortest.js
 I am getting data in the JSON format, where I also get directions.

I am facing problems of calculating the co - ordinates(latitude, longitude) of the place or the directions which he gave. He will provide the instruction, length, position, time, length_caption, earth_direction, azimuth, turn_type, turn_angle. But not latitude and longitude. Will some one help me on this please. You can find the developer documentation [here](http://developers.cloudmade.com/wiki/routing-http-api/Response_structure)

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Shravan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation link you provided it clearly states the the following:

route_geometry: [Array of nodes from start to end in 4326 projection ([lat1,lon1],...,[latM,lonM])]

Aren't these the lat/longs you are after?

Comment: Actually he has given only 3 directions in the response(sample) but 8 latitude and longitude. So, confused.. WIll u give any solution regarding this.